# How can I obtain the hash of a .Net assembly used for Strong Names?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, assemblies, code-signing

When signing an assembly, a `hash value` is first created from the assembly. Then, the hash value is encrypted with the private key and placed, along with the public key. But is there a way to have this hash value of the assembly? (*Because it is also computed at runtime and compared with the one stored, decrypted.*)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use signtool.exe: signtool verify /v /pa mydll.dll | find "Hash"

Comment: For reference "signtool.exe" can be found in the following directory: "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool".  However, I also have instances under "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\WindowsKits\10" and "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin".  I'm not certain on which is the correct one to use.